# UIToolbars: different height thru code and designer

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, uitoolbar

Can not find where I did a mistake in creating toolbars.

1 - was created through the code, please see below

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
toolBar.barTintColor = theme.barTintColor
let share = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: nil, action: nil)         
items.append(share)
items.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil))
let trash = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: nil, action: nil)
self.view.addSubview(toolBar)

toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {           
   let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
   toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
   toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
   toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  //toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}
```

2 - was added thru designer

looks like they have different height and as a result different indentation above the UIBarButtonItems

[image: toolbars]

**EDIT 0**: In the storyboard, the `toolbar 2` configured by default

[image]

**EDIT 1**: visual debugger shows the `_UIToolbarContentView` from `toolbar 2` is higher then `_UIToolbarContentView` `toolbar 1` on `5px`.

```
<_UIToolbarContentView: 0x153e13190; frame = (0 0; 375 49); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d0236d80>>
Printing description of $28:
<_UIToolbarContentView: 0x15b9f08d0; frame = (0 0; 375 44); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d522af00>>
```

**EDIT 2**: This strange behaviour on iPhone X, on iPhone 6 all fine.

[image]

**Workaround**: if iPhone X, add this hack
`toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 49)`

Comment: This is quite possible and is difficult to diagnose without knowing how the second toolbar is setup in the storyboard.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, the `toolbar 2` configured by default, added screens

Comment: Interesting that's not the defaults I get.  The Autoresizing is different.  when I drop a UIToolbar onto a UIViewController in Interface Builder it is fixed to the bottom, left and right only and set to expand/shrink horizontally.  If I change it to your settings the toolbar vanishes entirely.  I think that might be the root of the problem as fixing it top and bottom would allow the height to vary.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, I'll play with it, thanks! just in case, I use `navigation controller`, so the toolbar was added thru `show toolbars` in attribute inspector

Comment: Now I have replicated that it does look like your settings.  Anyway it's 2:17 on the 25th of December so I should really go to bed.

Comment: I took another look at this and even with a simple test app that padding is always there on the iPhone X.  I can only assume that it is a part of the design of the interface on the iPhone X and I can't see anyway to change it.  All you can really do is design with it in mind.  Much in the same manner as the status bar is a different height on the iPhone X but there is nothing you can do but take account of it.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth, Thanks! Yeah, I did the workaround, added constraints, but as for me, developers should not do this kind of 5px hack, it's iOS, not android :))